# asp:table width in percentage is not working

Tags: asp.net, html-table, formatting

I'm trying to get a table to look correct.  When I use fixed width, the table is the size I'd like for it to be... but when I use %, it's like it's ignored.

Here is the code:

```
 <asp:Table ID="Times" runat="server" style="Width:100%;">
    <asp:TableRow BackColor="YellowGreen">
        <asp:TableCell Width="45%">
            <asp:Image ID="imgImage" runat="server" />
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell Width="55%" >xxxxxx xxxx xxxx<br /><br />
        8:xxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx<br />
        xxxxxxxxx x xxxx<br />
        xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxx</asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

What am I doing wrong?

VS 2010, vb.net, .net4, asp.net app

Here is the markup that is rendered:

```
 <table id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Times" style="Width:100%;">
<tr style="background-color:YellowGreen;">
    <td style="Width:45%"><img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_imgImage" src="Images\SlideShow\default\church.JPG" /></td><td style="Width:55%">Sunday Service Times<br /><br />
        8:45 Fellowship Time<br />
        9:00 Sunday School<br />
        10:15 Church Services</td>
</tr>
```

and here is the aspx code.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false"
CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<asp:Table ID="Times" runat="server" Width="100%">
    <asp:TableRow BackColor="YellowGreen">
        <asp:TableCell  Width="45%">
            <asp:Image ID="imgImage" runat="server" />
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell  Width="55%" >Sunday Service Times<br /><br />
        8:45 Fellowship Time<br />
        9:00 Sunday School<br />
        10:15 Church Services</asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
</asp:Content>
```

the master page

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb" Inherits="MasterPage" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body background='<%=ResolveClientUrl("images\wood2.jpg")%>'>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="header" style="padding: 5px 5px 2px; text-align: center; width: 400px;">
    <asp:Image ID="imgSCC" runat="server" ImageUrl="images\hdrpic.jpg" />
    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" SiteMapProvider="Menu"
        ShowStartingNode="false" />
    <asp:Menu ....>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Is it the same in all browsers? It is inside another table or div?

Comment: Looks fine to me as well...Are you able to use something like Firebug to look at all the styles being applied to the table...OR include a screenshot showing what isn't displaying correctly?

Comment: please add more of the aspx code around your table control.

Comment: Can you show us the rendered markup for this table (i.e., the HTML sent to the browser for this `<asp:Table>` control)?

Comment: Well.. i kind of figured it out... I had not set a fixed width for the page in the header.... once i did that.. the percentages fell in place.  My ignorance.  Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works great if `Width="100%"` instead of `style="width=100%;"` (eventually it does the same thing)
What resolution are you referencing when you say **fixed width looks good**

`percentage` is good when you want your page to look correct @ various resolutions

Comment: I've tried that and the table does not take up the 100%.  for the fixed width i tried it for 1024

Comment: it should be **style="width:100%;"** or **Width:"100%"**